# Keras loss function is always negative

Tags: keras, tf.keras, bayesian-networks

I have implemented a Keras-based, **Bayesian** Deep Learning model (based on [this repo](https://github.com/kyle-dorman/bayesian-neural-network-blogpost))

My **model's loss appears to be always negative** as well as the logits_variance_loss (see screenshot below). Any idea why is this happening or what does it mean for the training? [image: training screenshot].

And this is after 2 epochs[image][image]

Comment: The link to the repo points to an image (not to a repository).

Comment: Sorry my mistake, URL now is fixed